# El-table-column prop with several values in an array

Tags: javascript, properties, element, element-ui

I want to display on table column (I'm using Element-UI), a prop that has several values in a specific array. In my case, it's the array in settings that has 2 max values, a main label and a secondary label. I want to fetch and display the specific value of label as an array (value1, value2). I can fetch it if I use the property: `prop="settings.0.label"` or `prop="settings.1.label"`, but I need to display both. Here's an image of the array structure. [Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRW8j.png)

Here's also the code of the table-column:

```
<el-table-column prop="settings" label="Status" sortable
    :sort-orders="['ascending', 'descending']" />
<el-table-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom template to define your own content within a cell.

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          name: 'Tom',
          settings: [{
            value: 'first'
          }, {
            value: 'second'
          }]
        }, {
          name: 'John',
          settings: [{
            value: 'first'
          }, {
            value: 'second'
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-table ref="filterTable" :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Status">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{ scope.row.settings[0].value }} - {{ scope.row.settings[1].value }}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```

Or you could define your own formatter:

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      formatter(row, column) {
        return `${row.settings[0].value} - ${row.settings[1].value}`
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        tableData: [{
          name: 'Tom',
          settings: [{
            value: 'first'
          }, {
            value: 'second'
          }]
        }, {
          name: 'John',
          settings: [{
            value: 'first'
          }, {
            value: 'second'
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.1/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-table ref="filterTable" :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180"></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="settings" label="Status" :formatter="formatter"></el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```